# Estou com erro no latex no windows 10 32 bits

Tags: windows

No Texmaker ou TexStudio sempre dá erro:

```
Error: Could not start the command.
```

O que será?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já instalou o MiKTeX no Windows 10?

Baixe em:

http://miktex.org/download